# Gauging away phases of SSH Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, fermions, topological-insulators, lattice-model

I'm reading 'A short course on Topological Insulators' in which it talks about adding phases to the SSH model that can easily be gauged away
$$
H=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & v & 0 & 0\\
v &0&w&0\\
0&w&0&v\\
0&0&v&0\\
\end{bmatrix}
\Rightarrow H_{\phi}=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & |v|e^{i\phi_{v}} & 0 & 0\\
|v|e^{-i\phi_{v}} &0&|w|e^{i\phi_{w}}&0\\
0&|w|e^{-i\phi_{w}}&0&|v|e^{i\phi_{v}}\\
0&0&|v|e^{-i\phi_{v}}&0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
In the book it is claimed that a change of basis can gauge away these phases, is there instead a unitary transformation such that $UH_{\phi}U^{\dagger}=H$ ? How do i go about finding such unitary transformations for similar systems? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have $v=|v|$, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The diagonal phase matrix $U= e^{i \alpha} {\rm diag} (e^{-i \phi_v}, 1, e^{i \, \phi_w}, e^{i(\phi_v+\phi_w)})$ does the job ($\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ is arbitrary).